# How transform that array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

i have a problem.

I have that array of objects:

```js
const iHaveThis = [{
    question: "What's your name?",
    answer: 'dda',
    form_filled_key: 15,
  },
  {
    question: "What's your e-mail?",
    answer: 'sda@br.com',
    form_filled_key: 15,
  },
  {
    question: "What's your e-mail?",
    answer: 'dAS@be.bimc',
    form_filled_key: 14,
  },
  {
    question: "What's your name?",
    answer: 'DAS',
    form_filled_key: 14,
  },
];
```

I want transform it to:

```js
const iWillHaveThis = [{
    "What's your e-mail?": 'sda@br.com',
    "What's your name?": 'dda',
  },

  {
    "What's your e-mail?": 'dAS@be.bimc',
    "What's your name?": 'DAS',
  },
];
```

How can i make that ? Please

I already tried use reduce, map but not working.

Comment: @MarkMeyer yes, i fixed it, sorry

Comment: Is form_filled_key the determining field on wither or not the objects belong together? If so you should mention that criteria in the question otherwise you need to explain what is the determining factor

Comment: So, there may be one or more objects

Comment: @PatrickEvans Yesss,it is form_filled_key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make an object keyed to your `form_filled_key`. And in a loop add objects to the object using the key to group them. In the end, your solution will be in the `Object.values()` of the object you built:

```js
const iHaveThat = [
  {question: "What's your name?",answer: 'dda',form_filled_key: 15,},
  {question: "What's your e-mail?",answer: 'sda@br.com',form_filled_key: 15,},
  {question: "What's your e-mail?",answer: 'dAS@be.bimc',form_filled_key: 14,},
  {question: "What's your name?",answer: 'DAS',form_filled_key: 14,},];

let arr = iHaveThat.reduce((obj, {form_filled_key, question, answer}) => {

    // make a new entry if needed
    if (!obj[form_filled_key]) obj[form_filled_key] = {}

    // add the key value pair
    obj[form_filled_key][question] = answer

    return obj
},{})

// you just want the array from `values()`
let result = Object.values(arr)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 3):

Hope this help

```
iHaveThat.map((v) => ({
   [v.question]:v.answer
}))
```

**EDIT**

```
var obj = {};
iHaveThat.forEach((v) => {
 // Checking if the key is available in the object or not. 
 //If key isn't available it will create the object for the key.
 if(!obj[v.form_filled_key])
  obj[v.form_filled_key] = { }
 // If object is already created we will just add new field in the object
 obj[v.form_filled_key][v.question] = v.answer
})
// To convert object into array of objects.
obj = Object.values(obj)
```

Comment: That wouldnt combine the objects, that would just produce a 1to1 transform which op isnt after

Comment: Hello Adill, thanks for your answer.. i already tried it but as Patrick told, it doesnt combine the objects

Comment: You should add a description/explanation of what your code is doing. Code dumps dont teach.

Answer (score 1):

Use `reduce`.

```js
const iHaveThis = [{question:"What's your name?",answer:'dda',form_filled_key:15,},{question:"What's your e-mail?",answer:'sda@br.com',form_filled_key:15,},{question:"What's your e-mail?",answer:'dAS@be.bimc',form_filled_key:14,},{question:"What's your name?",answer:'DAS',form_filled_key:14,}];

const res = Object.values(iHaveThis.reduce((a, { question, answer, form_filled_key }) => {
  (a[form_filled_key] = a[form_filled_key] || {})[question] = answer;
  return a;
}, {}));

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also create an `ES6 generator` to batch the array by `2` and then `Array.reduce` over it:

```js
const arr = [
  { question: "What's your name?", answer: 'dda', form_filled_key: 15, },
  { question: "What's your e-mail?", answer: 'sda@br.com', form_filled_key: 15, },
  { question: "What's your e-mail?", answer: 'dAS@be.bimc', form_filled_key: 14, },
  { question: "What's your name?", answer: 'DAS', form_filled_key: 14, },
];

function* batch (arr, n=2) {
  let i = 0
  while (i < arr.length) {
    yield arr.slice(i, i + n).reduce((r,c) => (r[c.question] = c.answer, r), {})
    i += n
  }
}

let result = [...batch(arr)]

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `(object[key] = object[key] || {})` pattern can be used to add values if they don't exist :

```js
const arr = [{question: "What's your name?",answer: 'dda',form_filled_key: 15,},{question: "What's your e-mail?",answer: 'sda@br.com',form_filled_key: 15,},{question: "What's your e-mail?",answer: 'dAS@be.bimc',form_filled_key: 14,},{question: "What's your name?",answer: 'DAS',form_filled_key: 14}]

const result = Object.values(arr.reduce((o, v, i) => 
    ((o[i = v.form_filled_key] = o[i] || {})[v.question] = v.answer, o), {}))

console.log( result )
```